# React Native : ListView is not working for andriod

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I am working on application where I am using `ScrollView`, what I want to achieve when user run application then I want some space from top . Now it working fine for IOS I mean when I run application on IOS it working fine and it generate the space from top but when I try for android it not working could someone please help me how to achieve my goal thanks .

**Code**

```
  handleScroller = value => {
    this.listView.scrollTo({ y: 200 });
  };



<KeyboardListener
            onWillShow={() => {
              this.scrollViewRef.scrollTo({ y: 200 });
            }}
            onWillHide={() => {
              this.scrollViewRef.scrollTo({ y: 0 });
            }}
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It look like you are using `KeyboardListener` library.

Somehow it still doesn't work in android. You need to pass `onDidShow()` and `onDidHide()` to `KeyboardListener` component.

```
<KeyboardListener
            onWillShow={() => {
              this.scrollViewRef.scrollTo({ y: 200 });
            }}
            onWillHide={() => {
              this.scrollViewRef.scrollTo({ y: 0 });
            }}
            onDidShow={() => {
              this.scrollViewRef.scrollTo({ y: 230 });
            }}
            onDidHide={() => {
              this.scrollViewRef.scrollTo({ y: 0 });
            }}
          />
```